# Is there a fiber / optical extension you can buy move your FTTP point?

Tags: cable, broadband, fiber, extension, optical-cable

I want to move my BT Openreach fiber box so it's running from my UPS.
Issue is the fiber cable into the building is 10 meters away from I need it to be.

Is there a fiber / optical extension you can buy to overcome this?

[image: Image: Green fiber cable in question]

[image: Image: BT Openreach box]

Comment: It strikes me as a lot cheaper and easier to extend the power from the UPS to the router than to extend the fibre cable from the termination point to where the UPS is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these boxes support a BBU (Battery Back Up), so it might be interesting to investigate acquiring one of these. I've found some literature that suggests they should "*come with*" a BBU, though I know that early VDSL modems from BT supported BBUs and didn't come with one (I never chased).

The quote below is from ["*How to build a Fibre network, Developer Guide*"](https://www.ournetwork.openreach.co.uk/resources/site1/General/Downloads/fibre_developer_handbook.pdf),  page 5 - I believe this is more targeted at new builds, but it might be worth asking / pushing for.

> When Openreach install the equipment we will supply the ONT, along with the battery back-up.

Page 8 of the same document shows the connector and notes potential issues due to contamination... unfortunately it doesn't name the connector, and I've not found it elsewhere... (it's not a secret... someone will know - @grawity and I suspect SC/APC)

It's worth bearing in mind that fiber doesn't typically get "extended", but rather spliced (fusing the two cores to form one continuous core) due to the losses, reflections, and other degradation to the signal. This isn't something that you'll be able to do yourself, and won't be something that the "standard" OpenReach guys can do either...

A user on the BT forums mentions a phone number for the FTTP team [ref](https://community.bt.com/t5/BT-Infinity-Fibre-broadband/Moving-FTTP-Openreach-Modem/m-p/1676766/highlight/true#M225980).

> 0800 587 4787 Is the FTTP team.
>
> Expect to have to pay.

This said... you ***could*** get a coupler, and a "singlemode" SC/APC cable (if our suspicions are correct about the connector and fiber type). This ***might*** work, but due to the nature of what you're dealing with, we cannot be sure.

For example:

- What is the signal's condition at the moment? (it's a run of unknown length, with an unknown transceiver at the other end)
- Will adding a coupler and an extra length degrade the signal such that the link is no longer stable / operational?

---

As an alternative, it may be worth looking into powering the router using PoE. I do this for my VDSL modem which is in an inconvenient corner of the house with *no* power - one wire and a box provides power and data, and it's also powered by the UPS.

[image: VDSL modem powered by PoE]

Comment: The connector looks like SC, and green means it's SC/APC. (This is probably the most common type for FTTP.) So I'm guessing you could get a premade singlemode fiber cable with SC/APC on both ends, and an [adapter](https://www.fiberopticcableshop.com/fiopadscsimo.html) to connect it to the existing one.

Comment: @grawity thanks - there's a better picture on page 8 of the linked document - it looks about right...

Comment: @grawity hah, your edit hints at something I was avoiding suggesting... I'll include it in my answer with a warning.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by @Attie and @grawity of using a coupler and an SC/APC cable proved to be successful.

Using a [15Mtr SC/APC-SC/APC 2mm Fibre Optic PatchCord](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/132419049162) with a [SC/APC-SC/APC Singlemode Simplex Fiber Optic Adapter Coupler](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/202280634163), I was able to move the fiber Openreach box as desired, with no drop in connectivity or speed.

[Image: SC/APC patchcord & coupler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5IwA.jpg)

Thank you both for the suggestion and clarification.