# Connect existing FTTP instalation to router with SFP?

Tags: networking, router, broadband, fiber, optical-cable

My existing FTTP installation by BT is using HG8240 GPON Terminal (model H35M8240BT06) + power backup.

I would like to completely remove HG8240 and connect it directly with mikrotik over SFP (saving one hop).

Q1: Will it work or BT requires you to have their gear?

Pictures of the fiber and modem can be seen in [Is there a fiber / optical extension you can buy move your FTTP point?](https://superuser.com/questions/1311719/is-there-a-fiber-optical-extension-you-can-buy-move-your-fttp-point?newreg=8052c991c0bd46bfb4f8358b51374d0f)

Current fiber cable is ending with green SC-P connector and I am in process of extending the fiber cable as described in link above.

Q2: I assume I need to have a GPON SFP module? (according to https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=140767 it needs to be from Huawei, one from mikrotik is discontinued for some reason)

Q3: Which type of GPON SFP do I need when extension cable is SC/APC?

Comment: I think _all_ GPON equipment is /APC due to its multi-device nature... Does BT have a procedure for "activating" a new ONT? I'm not sure how it's usually handled, but IIRC GPON terminals are authenticated by serial number _and_ decrypt data using username+password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm answering quite a lot later, but hopefully this might help someone one day.

Q1: It won't work. Although I'm from a different country and have no experience with BT, every ONT is configured by the fibre carrier/ISP. There is usually a rigorous onboarding process for new devices, so I doubt they'll let you BYOD even if you ask nicely.

Q2: Yes it would need to be GPON. Some ISPs do provide carrier certified GPON SFPs, however these are usually only permitted with enterprise-grade SLAs, and not for home connections. YMMV depending on your carrier/ISP.

Q3: To my knowledge all GPON SFPs use SC connectors. To find out if the receptacle is APC or UPC you'll need to check the SFP vendor's specs. You can purchase SC APC to SC UPC cables - the actual fibre is the same (make sure it's Single Mode); it's just the plug that's different.

Note: My experience is with Chorus networks in New Zealand.

HTH.